# Статические многомерные массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, память

Как я понял, элементы многомерного статического массива хранятся последовательно друг за другом в памяти.
И если в таком массиве

```
int array[2][2]
```

я хочу обратиться к элементу array[1][1], то я могу это сделать так:
`*(*(array + 1) + 1)`. Почему я не могу написать просто `*(array + 2 * 1 + 1)`? Ведь элементы рядышком?

Comment: Потому что элементами этого массива являются массивы `int [2]`, а не 2 x 2 инта. Но можно написать просто `arrray[1][1]`. А если хотите обращаться именно как написано в вопросе, то создавайте `int [4]`. А если действительно хочется попробовать многомерные массивы - то переходите на FORTRAN.

Comment: Тип `array` это массив массивов. `*(array + 2 * 1 + 1)` == `array[2 * 1 + 1]` - то есть четвёртый массив `int[2]` и вы выходите за пределы и возвращается **не** число а четвёртая строка матрицы.

Answer (score 3):

> Почему я не могу написать просто `*(array + 2 * 1 + 1)`?

Потому что тип указателя не тот. `*((int *)array + 2 * 1 + 1)` сработало бы, хотя формально стандарт запрещает такие выкрутасы (это неопределенное поведение).

`array[1][1]` здесь сработает, и ведет себя точно так же, как `*(*(array + 1) + 1)`.

У многомерных массивов нет каких-то особенных свойств - это просто массивы массивов.

Когда вы применяете `+` (или `*`, или еще много чего) к массиву, он преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Здесь тип элемента - `int[2]`, соответственно, тип указателя - `int (*)[2]`.

Когда к нему прибавляется первый индекс, указатель сдвигается на `i * sizeof(int[2])` (т.е. `i * 2 * sizeof(int)`) (умножение на размер типа, на который он указывает), поэтому самому умножать на `2` не нужно.

Затем `*` возвращает `int[2]`, и повторяется все то же самое. `+` преобразует его к `int *`, затем к нему прибавляется второй индекс, который умножается уже на `sizeof(int)`, и результат разыменовывается в `int`.

---

А предложенный `*(array + 2 * 1 + 1)` (если не скастовать указатель) мало того, что возвращает `int[2]`, а не `int`, так еще и выходит за границу массива.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы сделать так, как вы написали, вам нужно получить из указателя на указатель `int **array` просто одинарный указатель `int*`. Т.е. просто получить указатель на первый элемент массива в памяти. И далее работаете с двумерным массивом как с одномерным.

```
int array[2][2];
int *a = &array[0][0];
int b = *(a + 2 * 1 + 1);
```

По стандарту `c++` все многомерные массивы располагаются в памяти последовательно. И это работает с любыми многомерными массивами, не только двумерными.

```
int arr[3][3][3]; // будет последовательный кусок в памяти размером 27 int-ов
int *a = &arr[0][0][0];
*(a) = 1;
*(a+26) = 27;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139616/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitryk---).

Answer (score -1):

Потому что двумерный массив не совсем двумерный. Это скорее **массив массивов**.
Создается указатель на указатели(т.е. массив, содержащий указатели как свои элементы ), которые в свою очередь указывают уже на **одномерные массивы**.

`*(*(arr+1)+1)` даст доступ к `arr[1][1]`. `*(arr+1)` дает второй элемент массива, но т.к. это **массив указателей**, то этот элемент-указатель. А потом уже *он*(назовем его `р`) смещается на +1 `*(p+1)` и получаем уже реальный элемент массива, который хотим.
Как же это все хранится в памяти? Сначала идет массив из указателей, на начало которого указывает страшный указатель на указатели(он кстати и является именем массива, которое пишем). А потом, вовсе  **не обязательно подряд**(во всяком случае с динамическими массивами точно, у вас же статический, в нем строки матрицы(двумерного массива) могут лежать друг за другом, но я не настолько опытен, чтобы сказать однозначно), лежат строки нашего двумерного массива в виде простых одномерных массивов и на них(каждый на свою) указывают те указатели, лежащие в массиве из указателей.

Вот generic картинка из интернета, которая наглядно показывает написанное выше. Надеюсь немного помог)
[image]

Comment: Для статического массива никакие указатели в памяти не хранятся, и элементы лежвт строго подряд.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а тогда почему работает *(*(arr+i)+j) ?

Comment: Из-за автоматического превращения массива в указатель на свой первый элемент (здесь это происходит дважды, для `arr` и для `arr[i]`). У меня ж про это целый огромный ответ рядом.